# What is the a[n] for this sequence and its ∑ a[n] (k=1..12)

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the $a_{n}$ for this sequence? 
$$\left \{333, 2\cdot 333+0.1\cdot \frac{333}{12}, 3\cdot 333+0.1\cdot2\cdot \frac{333}{12},4\cdot333+0.1\cdot3\cdot \frac{333}{12},\dots, a_{n}\right \}.$$
And what is the answer for $\sum_{k=1}^{12}a_{n}$?

Comment: Hint: each step seems to add an extra $333\left(1+\dfrac{0.1}{12}\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that $$a_n=333 \,n + \frac {333}{12\times 10}\,(n-1)=\big(333+\frac {333}{120}\big)\,n-\frac {333}{120}=\frac{13431}{40}n-\frac {333}{120}$$ So $$\sum_{n=1}^m a_n=\frac{13431}{40}\sum_{n=1}^m n-\frac {333}{120}\sum_{n=1}^m 1$$ Now, remember that the first sum is just $\frac{1}{2} m (m+1)$ and the second sum is just $m$ .

I am sure that you can take from here.